# Looking for interceptors for grails service class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Is there any  interceptor I can use to validate incoming requests to the Grails service classes/Endpoints? 
I know interceptors  for controllers but I want to do it for Service/endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like what you are looking for:
[Intercepting Service Methods](http://redpointtech.blogspot.com/2010/03/grails-intercepting-service-class.html)

Comment: I'm using PayloadValidatingInterceptor and mapping to endpoint to validate the request.It seems to be working fine.. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In the link mentioned above(Kelly's reply), interceptor logic for Service has been added in BootStrap class. That might suffice in most of the cases but not all. In case you are using Quartz scheduler then job might get triggered even before BootStrap has made required modifications.

The best place to modify a service method would be via [custom plugin](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html). You can decorate service method in doWithApplicationContext or doWithDynamicMethod available in Plugin class. These methods are triggered at first and guarantee that changes made will be available to all other classes. Please refer Grails custom plugin documentation for more information.